# I want to find the limit of a specific function

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+}\frac{\exp \left[-\alpha\left( \frac{1}{x^{\beta}} -1\right) \right] }{x^{1+\beta}}$$
where $ \alpha>0 $ and $ \beta>0 $ are given constants

Answer (score 2):

Let $y=\frac1x \to \infty$ then

$$\frac{e^{-\alpha\left(\frac1{x^\beta}-1\right)}}{x^{1+\beta}}
=\frac{y^{1+\beta}}{e^{\alpha\left(y^\beta-1\right)}}
=e^\alpha\cdot\frac{y^{1+\beta}}{e^{\alpha y^\beta}}\to 0$$

indeed eventually

$$e^{\alpha y^\beta}\ge y^{2+\beta} \implies \frac{y^{1+\beta}}{e^{\alpha y^\beta}}\le \frac{y^{1+\beta}}{y^{2+\beta}}=\frac1y \to 0$$

Comment: but $e^x\longrightarrow 0 $, when $x\rightarrow -\infty$

Comment: @hamzaboulahia Opsss....thanks I fix!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. We have $\alpha>0,\,\beta>0$ then, for some $c(\alpha,\beta)>0$,
$$
\exp \left(\frac{\alpha}{x^{\beta}}\right)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{\alpha}{x^{\beta}}\right)^n}{n!}\ge \frac{c(\alpha,\beta)}{x^{\beta+2}},\qquad x>0,
$$ giving, as $x \to 0^+$,
$$
\left|\frac{\exp \left[-\alpha\left( \frac{1}{x^{\beta}} -1\right) \right] }{x^{1+\beta}} \right|\le \frac{e^{\alpha}x^{\beta+2}}{x^{\beta+1}c(\alpha,\beta)}=\frac{e^{\alpha}x}{c(\alpha,\beta)}\to 0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

We have,
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\exp \left[-\alpha\left( \frac{1}{x^{\beta}} -1\right) \right] }{x^{1+\beta}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+}e^\alpha\frac{e^{ \frac{-\alpha}{x^{\beta}} }  }{x^{1+\beta}}$$
Then we substitute $\dfrac{1}{x}=u$, then
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}e^\alpha\frac{e^{ \frac{-\alpha}{x^{\beta}} }  }{x^{1+\beta}}=\lim_{u\rightarrow +\infty}e^\alpha e^{ -\alpha  u^{\beta} }  u^{1+\beta}$$
We know that the polynomial functions are negligible in front of the exponential in the vicinity of infinity, 
$$\lim_{u\rightarrow +\infty}e^\alpha e^{ -\alpha  u^{\beta} }  u^{1+\beta}=\lim_{u\rightarrow +\infty} e^{ -\alpha  u^{\beta} }=0,\quad \mbox{since }  \alpha>0,\ \beta>0   $$